# How do I perform a search in android when the user presses the hardware search button?

Tags: android, android-search

I'm using this for software search (search that collapses in the menu when the user presses the magnifying glass) and it works perfectly :

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_entries, menu);
        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.viewMenu_search).getActionView();
        int id = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(id);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        textView.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                ViewEntries.this.customAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                return true;
            }
        });
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }
```

My question is : how do I get the search query string (the one like the parameter String s) when the user starts the search using the hardware button. I tried this, but the intent I get is not the search intent, but the one that started the activity (so I never enter the if):

```
@Override
    public boolean onSearchRequested() {
        Intent intent1 = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String s = intent1.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            ViewEntries.this.customAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
        return super.onSearchRequested();
    }
```

I also say when debugging on the emulator that onSearchRequested is called the moment you start the search, not after you enter the query. Maybe a hint on how to get the searchview there (id or something)?

Comment: How many (current) android devices are there with a hardware search button?

Comment: I just have to do it... I know, I know...

Comment: No judgement, just curious. I know there are *those* requirements ;)